# Как должен работать CardView?

Tags: android, android-sdk, cardview

Добрый день.

Выполняю задание: 
1) В карточке отобразить результат для n-го поста (должна быть возможность вписать n в карточку и нажать «Подтвердить» для отображения результата).
Если я  правильно понял то карточка(CardView) это виддже\контейнер, которую часто используют вместе RecyclerView(Список)?  Как вообще должна проходить логика работы CardView?

К примеру:  у меня в приложении несколько CardView ввиде квадратов. В одном из них будет поле для ввода и кнопка подтвердить. Я ввожу туда n нажимаю кноку "Подтвердить" и меня кидает на другую активити? Или внутри карточки должна информация отобразиться?

2) Вторая карточка users - отобразить результат первых 5-ти пользователей в единой карточке (в 5 линий). Что значит " в единой карточке" и как это должно работать?

Comment: CardView это всего лишь контейнер FrameLayout с фоном в виде "визитки", никакой магии от этого ждать не приходится

Comment: на другую активити переходить не надо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду CardView - то это всего лишь вьюшка, это такой же слой, как FrameLayout (FrameLayout его родитель)

Надо добавить его в build.gradle (Module:app), для начала:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
}
```

В макете создаётся так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Многие важные свойства устанавливаются через app:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Например, `app:cardCornerRadius` задаёт закругление карточки.

Относитесь к нему, как к слою на макете. В него надо положить другие вьюшки, чтобы он что-то отображал.

Официальная статья должна помочь:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru